# SMTP Authentication error while sending mail using microsoft 365 mail id

Tags: python, email

i want to send mail using microsoft 365 mail id which is MFA Enabled...

here is the code i tried

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart

# Replace these with your actual values
sender_email = 'sendermail.com'
app_password = 'pwd'
recipient_email = 'recipientmai.com'

# Create a MIME message
message = MIMEMultipart()
message['From'] = sender_email
message['To'] = recipient_email
message['Subject'] = 'Test Email'
body = 'This is a test email sent using smtplib.'
message.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))

# Connect to the SMTP server
with smtplib.SMTP('smtp.office365.com', 587) as server:
    server.starttls()
    # Login with your email and app password
    server.login(sender_email, app_password)
    # Send the email
    server.sendmail(sender_email, recipient_email, message.as_string())

print('Email sent successfully!')
```

when i executed above , i got the following error

```
Authentication unsuccessful, user is locked by your organization's security defaults policy. Contact your administrator
```

please help me to fix this error